# How do I access the activity_main from the secondary procedure

Tags: java, android, textview

I created a dynamic `TextView` with the following sequence:

```
Cre_TextView ("t3",10,(left10*ux),(top10*uy),(width10*ux),(height10*uy),"FFFFFFFF","FF000000", "",24,0,1,0);
```

I have below :

```java
public final void Cre_TextView(String p1, int p2, float p3, float p4, float p5, float p6, String p7, String p8, String p9, int p10, int p11, int p12, int p13) {
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString((CharSequence) p9);
    if (p11 == 1){
        spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(1), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(2), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
    } 
    else {
        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(1), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(0), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View var10000 = this.findViewById(p12);
    RelativeLayout baza = (RelativeLayout) var10000;
    TextView tv = new TextView((Context) this);
    tv.setId(p2);
    tv.setX(p3);
    tv.setY(p4);
    tv.setWidth((int) p5);
    tv.setHeight((int) p6);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + p7));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#" + p8));

    if (p13 == 1) 
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reflected_gradient_effect);

    if (p13 == 2) 
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);

    tv.setGravity(17);
    tv.setTextSize((float) p10 * uy);
    tv.setText((CharSequence) spanString);
    baza.addView((View) tv);
}
```

I created this `TextView` in the main procedure with ID number 10. In a secondary procedure you had to assign a value via `setText()`. How do I access the dynamically created `TextView` in the main procedure?